# how to get the pipeline name dynamically in ADF?

Tags: pipeline, azure-data-factory

I am trying to implement mail notification in pipeline in ADF.

So basically I want to send the a notification mail about the successful execution of pipeline in ADF.
I have created a demo pipeline where I m coping the data. this is working fine.
And I have created a SSIS pkg that will send email notification(also working fine.)

Now I want to have the pipeline name so that the notification will have pipeline name also dynamically.

Comment: ADF : Azure Data Factory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following expression which uses system variables to get the current pipeline name:

```
@pipeline().Pipeline
```

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables?) for more system variables.